# How can slices be split using another slice as a delimiter?

Tags: rust

Does the standard library provide a way to split a slice `[T]` using another slice of the same type as a delimiter? The library's documentation lists methods that operate on single-element delimiters rather than slices.

For example: A slice of 5 `u64` integers `[1u64, 4u64, 0u64, 0u64, 8u64]` split using `[0u64, 0u64]` as a delimiter would result in two slices `[1u64, 4u64]` and `[8u64]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the standard library provide a way to split a slice `[T]` using another slice of the same type as a delimiter?

As of Rust 1.9, no, but you can implement it:

```
fn main() {
    let a = [1, 4, 7, 0, 0, 8, 10, 0, 0];
    let b = [0, 0];
    let mut iter = split_subsequence(&a, &b);
    assert_eq!(&[1, 4, 7], iter.next().unwrap());
    assert_eq!(&[8, 10], iter.next().unwrap());
    assert!(iter.next().unwrap().is_empty());
    assert_eq!(None, iter.next());
}

pub struct SplitSubsequence<'a, 'b, T: 'a + 'b> {
    slice: &'a [T],
    needle: &'b [T],
    ended: bool,
}

impl<'a, 'b, T: 'a + 'b + PartialEq> Iterator for SplitSubsequence<'a, 'b, T> {
    type Item = &'a [T];

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.ended {
            None
        } else if self.slice.is_empty() {
            self.ended = true;
            Some(self.slice)
        } else if let Some(p) = self.slice
                                    .windows(self.needle.len())
                                    .position(|w| w == self.needle) {
            let item = &self.slice[..p];
            self.slice = &self.slice[p + self.needle.len()..];
            Some(item)
        } else {
            self.ended = true;
            let item = self.slice;
            self.slice = &self.slice[self.slice.len() - 1..];
            Some(item)
        }
    }
}

fn split_subsequence<'a, 'b, T>(slice: &'a [T], needle: &'b [T]) -> SplitSubsequence<'a, 'b, T>
    where T: 'a + 'b + PartialEq
{
    SplitSubsequence {
        slice: slice,
        needle: needle,
        ended: false,
    }
}
```

Note that this implementation uses a [naive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) algorithm for finding an equal subsequence.

Comment: The naïve algorithm is O(n^2), I believe, which is part of the reason it's not included in the standard library.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. +1 for taking the time to illustrate your response with an implementation.