# How can I split a vector into a vector of slices based on a separator?

Tags: rust

If I have a vector such as

```
let mut bytes = vec![0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x40, 0x04, 0x05, 0x40, 0x06, 0x40];
```

I want to separate the vector by the `0x40` separator. Is there a clean way of doing this functionality?

expected output: 
`[[0x01, 0x02, 0x03], [0x04, 0x05], [0x06]]`

Comment: Take a look at [`Vec::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.split)

Answer (score 7):

Use [`slice::split`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split):

```rust
fn main() {
    let bytes = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x40, 0x04, 0x05, 0x40, 0x06, 0x40];
    let pieces: Vec<_> = bytes
        .split(|&e| e == 0x40)
        .filter(|v| !v.is_empty())
        .collect();
    println!("{:?}", pieces)
}
```

See also:

- [How can slices be split using another slice as a delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38821671/155423)
- [In Rust, what's the idiomatic way to split a &str into an iterator of &strs of one character each?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59597751/155423)